# More Easy vs More Easily

Tags: adjectives

[image]

Why would it be more easily instead of more easy?

Comment: In the future, please consider posting questions like this on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) The guidelines for forming comparatives of adverbs are  fairly straight- forward. [That's a hint i.e. it's not an adjective.]

Answer (score 0):

**Welcome to English Language & Usage**

Thanks for your question.

"The water flowed easily into ~." is a basic sentence structure.

"flowed" is a verb and "easily" is an adverb which modifies the verb "flowed".

"Adverb" modifies "verb", so easily is correct.

"more" is also an adverb which modifies "easily".

Adverbs modify almost everything(mainly verbs, adjectives, adverbs); adverbs are additional information in sentences.